# image capture and manipulation

Tags: image, audio

I'm a noob here, so want to firstly say HI :)

Can I ask a question. I'm OK with C and C++ (I know different beasts) and wondered can anyone suggest a good source of info for turning sound waves into images?

My question is this. How do you capture things like waves (you know like images or fetus) and turn it into an actual image. I've looked on the internet and am really curious how this happens. I kinda suspect that it has something to do with the transducer that they put on a women's stomach.

My next question is how do they catch that echo/wave and turn it into the image - I suspect it is programmed in something small and fast like C/C++. Does anyone know an algorithm?

Thank you all for your time in reading and any answers/links/references

Once again really happy to be here :)

Comment: There is a TI paper on one of their DSPs http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=sprab32, Also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation

Comment: This is an "image processing" question, not an "image" and "processing" question (when you hover over the tag, it explains what it's for. The "Processing" tag is very much not for this question =)

Comment: Thanks for that @jlujan I'll investgate this further. Maths looks quite complex but I'll get to grips with it :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is about Processing (the programming environment) *and* digital signal processing (i.e. DSP)

First, let me introduce you to your new best friend: the Fast Fourier transform. I found a great introductory article for you by [Paul Bourke.](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/dft/)

If you want to go a little deeper, checlk out: ["The DFT “à Pied”: Mastering The Fourier Transform in One Day"](http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/dft-a-pied/).

The math for FFT. isn't as hard as you think it might be, and growing at a basic understanding for what's happening under the scenes will help you to properly implement a library (of which there are many) in whatever language you choose to utilize: C++ or Processing (Java). Check out the article, your brain will love you for it.

Here's another [article about FFT:](http://sharp.bu.edu/~slehar/fourier/fourier.html)

A great professor of mine wrote a dope FFT implementation in OpenFrameworks (C++) https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxFft that is absolutely worth your time if you currently have (or ar interested in getting) OpenFrameworks up and running.

However, if you want to jump into directly into playing with FFT code in processing, Minim is one library which has FFT functionality, which you can read about [here.](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/javadoc/ddf/minim/analysis/FFT.html)

Good luck!

Comment: Many, many thanks @Justin Lange. I'll certainly check that out